# Dual boot with offline disks

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, bootloader

I have a setup with 2 Windows installations in the same machine (different physical disks) and I'm keeping them separated, meaning that each installation has the other one's disk as "offline".

This forces me to use my UEFI boot setup everytime I need to switch between my installations, and to use it I have to disable fast boot or I won't be able to enter UEFI settings.

I'm looking for a way to have the bootloader show both of them, or even simply having a Windows shortcut to reboot to other drive.

Is this possible?

EDIT:

> bcdedit /v

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identificatore          {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795}
device                  partition=\Device\Harddisk1\Partition5
path                    \EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  it-IT
inherit                 {7ea2e1ac-2e61-4728-aaa3-896d9d0a9f0e}
default                 {89bec29f-b9f0-11e8-833a-c71da893bdb0}
resumeobject            {89bec29e-b9f0-11e8-833a-c71da893bdb0}
displayorder            {89bec29f-b9f0-11e8-833a-c71da893bdb0}
toolsdisplayorder       {b2721d73-1db4-4c62-bf78-c548a880142d}
timeout                 0
displaybootmenu         No

Caricatore di avvio di Windows
-------------------
identificatore          {89bec29f-b9f0-11e8-833a-c71da893bdb0}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  it-IT
inherit                 {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-0ee5eff72bd7}
recoverysequence        {91ba0e4b-55d0-11e8-9730-c824ecd906f0}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {89bec29e-b9f0-11e8-833a-c71da893bdb0}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
```

Answer (score 1):

For booting from one Windows version into the other one, use the
[BCDEdit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc709667%28v=ws.10%29) command.

Running it once without parameters will list all the installations currently
in the UEFI store, so you can identify the two Windows installations by
their name and GUID.

You may then in one Windows installation create a shortcut similar to the 
following and using the GUID of the other Windows installation :

```
bcdedit /bootsequence e {975a8204-9658-11dd-993e-9aea7965e9da}
```

The `bootsequence` parameter is defined as :

> Specifies a one-time display order to be used for the next boot. This command is similar to the /displayorder option, except that it is used only the next time the computer starts. Afterwards, the computer reverts to the original display order.

Comment: Running `bcdedit` only shows one installation. My guess is that this needs both disks to be online to work, which is not my scenario.

Comment: Yes, it does. Could you add to your post an explanation of : What you mean by offline? Aren't both disks spinning? Why doesn't the UEFI database contain both installations? Exactly how are you booting one or the other?

Comment: Offline means not mounted in Windows. UEFI is set so that it boots from Windows Boot Manager on the first disk, if I need to switch to the second drive I have to get to UEFI boot options and manually select WBM on the second drive.

Comment: How exactly are you manually selecting WBM on the second drive?

Comment: "UEFI boot options", as said before. [Bottom right menu](https://3dnews.ru/assets/external/illustrations/2015/04/26/913291/01_asusS99S_bios_big.jpg)

Comment: Then the UEFI knows all your installations. I don't really understand why you cannot find its GUID. You might look to see if your UEFI firmware has an update. What is the computer?

Comment: I think that UEFI only knows that I have WBM in both disks. WBM itself probably has no way to know that there's another installation in an unmounted drive.

Comment: Could you add to your post the output of `bcdedit /v`?

Comment: Another question: Did the second disk come from another computer and Windows on it was never installed on this computer?

Comment: Second one was cloned from the first one.

Comment: Right, so both disks now have a copy of the same UEFI that only knows about the first disk. I suggest searching in the menu of the UEFI of the first disk the function of "add item" or similar in order to add the second disk to the UEFI Store on the first disk. I can't help you there, since I most likely don't know your UEFI version.